# Renaming and moving files and folders with bash script

Tags: bash

I'm trying to make a bash script that goes to every single folder and then renames all the files in the folders numerically. There are multiple folders and multiple files within the folders. I want to rename all of them and then transfer all of the files to a single folder. The code I have so far is

```
#! /bin/bash
FOLDERS=$(ls *)
COUNT=0
for folder in $FOLDERS
    do
        cd $folder
        FILE=$(ls *)
            for file in $FILE
                do
                    echo "working on it"
                    COUNT=$((COUNT+1))
                    mv $file $COUNT
        cd ..
done
```

but it isn't working...

Any thoughts on how to do this?

Comment: [ShellCheck](https://www.shellcheck.net) would be a start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this will do the job:

```
#!/bin/bash
shopt -s globstar
source='/your/source/folder'
target='/your/target/folder'
i=0
for f in ${source}/**; do
    if [[ -f "${f}" ]]; then
       ((i++))
       mv "${f}" "${target}/${i}"
    fi
done
```

Comment: `for f in $(find` - will make `mv` fail if there is a space in the files filename. Or a newline. Or a tab.

Comment: @KamilCuk, indeed. But I'm assuming that's not the case. :-). Feel free to edit the answer and provide an alternative. I don't know how to handle that.

Comment: the thing is there are files with similar file name like 01, 02 ,etc so if I move it to a single big file, the identical files get removed. So I was thinking that maybe before I move it, I can first rename it so that I don't experience any problems while doing this.

Comment: Also, if it isn't too much of a hassle for you, it would really be helpful if you could explain the code so I understand how to use it in the future :)

Comment: @Sp00ky check ```--backup=t``` option for mv. mv can add suffix if file exists.

Comment: There is not much to explain, since the code is very simple and almost self-explanatory. The uncommon bit is ```shopt -s globstar```, which ```man bash``` describes it better than me: "When  the globstar  shell  option  is  enabled,  and * is used in a pathname expansion context, two adjacent  *s  used  as  a single  pattern  will  match  all  files and zero or more directories and subdirectories.  If followed by a /,  two adjacent  *s  will match only directories and subdirectories."

Answer (score -1):

You can do this in Ruby and hence, you don't have to worry about special characters in filenames :

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby

require 'find'
require 'fileutils'


source_dir="./"
target_dir="target/"
count = 0

Find.find(source_dir) do |path|
  next if path =~ /(.*\.rb$|.*\.\/$|.*\.\.\/$)/
  puts "Found : " + path
  File.rename(path,count.to_s) 
  FileUtils.mv(source_dir + count.to_s, target_dir)  
  count = count + 1
end
```

Regards!

Comment: Wow this is really complex! I really appreciate you taking the time to answer my question :)